# Connect to Docker Swarm for Continuous deploy

Tags: docker, continuous-deployment, docker-swarm, circleci, docker-cloud

Any suggestions on how best to connect to a swarm for continuous deploy (within CI)? I'm using docker cloud, and CircleCI 2.

Tried `dockercloud/client`

e.g.

```
docker run --rm -ti -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -e DOCKER_HOST dockercloud/client -u ${DOCKER_LOGIN} -p ${DOCKER_PASSWORD} myapp/app
```

However, since I'm using CircleCI 2 I'm having an issue when I switch to the other docker host as following

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://XXX:XXX. Is the docker daemon running?

This is an issue due to the remote docker they setup for security reasons from what I understand, so I don't think it's possible.

What I would like to achieve is simply to connect to the swarm and call `docker stack deploy ...`

Any help would be appreciated.